# Pourquoi "pourrir" prend deux "r"?

Tags: orthographe

D'après cette page https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pourir, "pourir" prenait autrefois un seul "r". Quelle est la raison pour laquelle aujourd'hui on l'écrit avec une consonne doublée?

Comment: Voir ici : https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pourrir/verbe#:~:text=d%C3%A9signe%20une%20mati%C3%A8re%20organique%5D%20Se,se%20putr%C3%A9fier.

Answer (score 1):

Some additional information:

In [Dictionnaire de l’Académie française](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A5P1784) it was spelled with double r up until the 5th edition, released 1798. 5th - 7th editions have it with single r, and then from 8th edition and onwards (1935 -) it was back to double r.